# Create mailto link in pdf working on Android

Tags: javascript, android, acrobat

I have a form made in indesign and exported as interactive form.  It works perfect in the computer, however when I open in the tablet Andoird (I tried app acrobat, pdf viewer, drive, samsung notes, .....) the submit button doesn't work.
I have two bottons: restore form and submit form as pdf.  Restore works well but submit doesnt.

Any idea the way I can configure a button in the form that works on Android to send the form once is filled?

This is what I have in the submit:

```
var customer=this.getField("Name").value;
var to="a@abc.com";
var toBcc="b@abc.com;ct@abc.com";
var mySubject="ORDER%202023%20-%20"+customer;
var myBody="body\n"+cliente;

var myURL="mailto:"+to+"?bcc"+toBcc+"&subject="+mySubject+"&body="+myBody;
this.submitForm({cURL: (myURL), cSubmitAs:"PDF", cCharSet:"utf-8"});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The good news: It is not your fault (assuming that the variable `cliente` is defined somewhere).

The bad news: There are very few (if any) PDF viewers which understand Acrobat Javascript for tablets. In any case, Adobe Acrobat Reader for Tablets does not.

I am not absolutely current with Android, but you might try qPDF from Qoppa (for iOS, I'd look at PDFExpert by Readdle). Not verified, but it is possible that a Chromium-based webbrowser may also be smart enough (such as Microsoft Edge).

If it is just the `submitForm()` method which is not recognised, you might look whether a link (instead of a button) would work.

Another workaround would be to setting up a section of a webserver, and submit the data to it, and have it send out eMails.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I'll try what you suggest, is good to confirm it was not my fault.